# connection error while connecting to mysql database in asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, odbc

here i want to display employee table  informtaion in a `gridview` from `mysql` database

**CODE**

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 ANSI Driver};Server=localhost;Database=test;uid=root;pwd=amritalikun;option=3");
OdbcCommand cmd;
OdbcDataReader rr;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from employee";
    con.Open();
    rr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = rr;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();

}
```

problem is whenever i debug my code it show the following error at con.Open() line

`An exception of type System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code`

`Additional information: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

i didnot get what is the error actually and need help how to resolve this.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install appropriate driver for **MySQL ODBC 3.51**

go to run and type odbcad32.exe then go to System DSN and check whether 
MySQL ODBC 3.51 drivers are installed or not